# Use activity window.attributes in Jetpack Compose to change screenBrightness

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am trying to modify screenBrightness through update this:

```
   window.attributes = window.attributes.apply { screenBrightness = 0.2f }
```

But I can get **window** in MainActivity : ComponentActivity() only. How to access is from Composable component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using this to modify screen brightness in Jetpack Compose

```
@Composable
fun ComposableComponent() {
  val activity = LocalView.current.context as? Activity
  if (activity != null) {
    activity.window?.attributes = activity.window.attributes.apply {
      screenBrightness = -1.0f
    }
  }
}
```